# how to create a interface with unknown number of properties in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create an interface with an unknown number of properties of type string in typescript.
eg: there could be 5 or maybe 50 property of type string
Is it possible in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to specify that a interface can have any number of properties:

```
interface MyInterface {
  knownPropert1: string;
  knownProperty2: string;
  [key: string]: string; // specify that any other properties will be of type string too
}
```