# typescript interface with key index generates error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand [how to create a interface with unknown number of properties in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387953/how-to-create-a-interface-with-unknown-number-of-properties-in-typescript) and I don't understand it because this code generates an error : why, I just want an object with any number of members of type I1

```
  interface I0 {
    [key: string]: I1;
  }

  class O implements I0 {
    m: {
      p1: "test",
      p2: "test"
    }
  }

  interface I1 {
    [key: string]: "string";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to declare properties that are provided by `implements`.

For example:

```
interface A { a: string }

class Foo implements A {
  constructor() { this.a = 'abc' }
}
// Class 'Foo' incorrectly implements interface 'A'.
//   Property 'a' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'A'.(2420)

class Bar implements A {
  a: string
  constructor() { this.a = 'abc' }
}
// Fine
```

That means you need to declare the index signature in your class as well.

```
class O implements I0 {
  [key: string]: I1

  m: {
    p1: "test",
    p2: "test"
  }
}
```

Here `implements` checks to make sure that the class supports interface `I0`, but that's *all* `implements` actually does.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=4.8.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAZkG8BQzkDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6lqAjANw4C+OOoksRCjbY8hEhWq0GzKXRD1OPXggA2cKlWQB5ZMAC2AB1UR9EcFoyj8xMpRrymLVr3z7KufPkOtKAIkgaPwAaMW8AJn9AsD8xHmUcIA)